# How to correctly override/overload typing of __call__

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, mypy, typing

I need to clarify type, returning by unified factory. I have singleton factory in separate file like this:

```py
from typing import Any, Type


class SingletonFactory:
    __slots__ = ('singleton_instance', )

    def __init__(self, singleton_class: Type[object], **singleton_init_params: Any):
        self.singleton_instance: object = singleton_class(**singleton_init_params)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # noqa: E501

    def __call__(self) -> object:
        return self.singleton_instance
```

Then in other file.

**Option 1:**

```py
from typing import Callable, overload

class Client:
   pass  # IRL have init params


client_factory: Callable[[], Client] = SingletonFactory(
    Client
)

client = client_factory()  # pyCharm see it as instance of object - expected Client
```

MyPy error:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "SingletonFactory", variable has type "Callable[[], Client]")  [assignment]
note: "SingletonFactory.__call__" has type "Callable[[], object]"
```

**Option 2:**

```py
from typing import Callable, overload

class Client:
   pass  # IRL have init params

@overload  # type: ignore[misc]
def client_factory() -> Client:
    ...


client_factory = SingletonFactory(
    Client
)

client = client_factory()  # pyCharm see it as instance of Client - what I expect
```

Works, but MyPy error same as above plus: `error: Single overload definition, multiple required  [misc]`.

**Option 3:**

```py
from typing import Callable, overload

class Client:
   pass  # IRL have init params


class ClientFactory(SingletonFactory):

    @overload  # type: ignore[misc]
    def __call__() -> Client:
        ...


client_factory = ClientFactory(
    Client
)

client = client_factory()  # pyCharm see it as instance of Client - what I expect
```

One less MyPy error, but inheriting `SingletonFactory` only for overload makes code cumbersome.

Is there any way to fully satisfy MyPy in this situation?

Comment: Could you make the `ClientFactory` _generic_, so it can determine the return type of `__call__` based on the argument to `__init__`? See e.g. https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=cc4b33572ac0253754cd0da94d6af4d2.

Comment: You are trying to make the class *variable* in the *type* of ``singleton_class`` – i.e. to use a [``TypeVar``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar).

Comment: What is ``lazy_args_kwargs`` supposed to be? The recent edit doesn't make much sense to me, and worse it effectively invalidates the existing answer.

Comment: Function that will return tuple and dict, that will be used as args and kwargs to instantiate class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [*generics*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics), to describe a relationship between the types of different variables in your code; one such implementation is demonstrated in the code below.

```
from typing import Callable, Generic, ParamSpec, TypeVar

P = ParamSpec("P")
T = TypeVar("T")


class SingletonFactory(Generic[T]):
    __slots__ = ('singleton_instance', )

    singleton_instance: T

    def __init__(
        self,
        singleton_class: Callable[P, T],
        *singleton_args: P.args,
        **singleton_kwargs: P.kwargs
    ):
        self.singleton_instance = singleton_class(*singleton_args, **singleton_kwargs)

    def __call__(self) -> T:
        return self.singleton_instance
```

Now the return type of `__call__` is based on the type of the first parameter to `__init__`:

```
class Thing: pass


t: Thing = SingletonFactory(Thing)()  # OK
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly specify a factory of a particular type somewhere by providing the generic type:

```
def my_func(factory: SingletonFactory[int]) -> int:
    return factory()
```

It should be noted that, rather than using `Type[T]`, `Callable[P, T]` has been used instead, with a [`ParamSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) (implemented in Python 3.10). When the program is it written this way, it allows the parameters to be checked too, based on the `singleton_class`:

```
class OtherThing:
    def __init__(self, foo: int, bar: str):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar


ot: OtherThing = SingletonFactory(OtherThing)()  # error: Missing positional arguments "foo", "bar" in call to "SingletonFactory"

ot = SingletonFactory(OtherThing, 123, bar="baz")()  # OK
```

*...and you no longer need `type: ignore[call-arg]`.*

[MyPy playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=b7ac9f6eb237983ac0b11ed310230c3b)

Comment: Very nice answer. Updated my question - got another one. Also python v.3.8 have `typing_extensions`, that has `ParamSpec` and it works: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=cf6fa8fcacfcca96e7e8f6d934f22dd5 - although PyCharm complains that 'Callable' must be used as 'Callable[[arg, ...], result]' and red underlines P in Callable[P, T]

Comment: @frenzy _"Updated my question - got another one"_ is **not** how to use SO ([chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/248731) are frowned upon).